# Hangfire .net core 404 Dashboard

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I am trying to deploy the Hangfire Dashboard for my api server that sits on Docker. Locally, when I run https://localhost:1234/hangfire, the page shows up properly. However, once it sits on Docker, for some reason, it just shows 404.

This is my startup.cs

```
public void Services(IServiceCollection services, string connstr)
{
    var mysqlOptions = new MySqlStorageOptions
    {
        TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
        QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
        DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
        TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        //TablesPrefix = "Hangfire"
    };
    services.AddHangfire(x => {
        x.UseStorage(new MySqlStorage(connstr, mysqlOptions));
    });
    services.AddHangfireServer();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    LoadConfigurationServices loadConfigurationServices = new LoadConfigurationServices();
    loadConfigurationServices.Configure(app, env);

    var staticFileCacheInSeconds = configuration[SDR_Core.ClassLibrary.Globals.ConfigurationGlobals.StaticFileCacheInSeconds];

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
            int durationInSeconds = Int32.Parse(staticFileCacheInSeconds);
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
        }
    });

    var culture = configuration[SDR_Core.ClassLibrary.Globals.ConfigurationGlobals.Culture];
    LoadCultureServices loadCultureServices = new LoadCultureServices();
    loadCultureServices.Configure(culture);
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints((config) =>
    {
        config.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "areas",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
        config.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
        config.MapRazorPages();
    });
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
}
```

On Docker, my url is http://localhost:1234/hangfire

Answer (score 0):

I find below tip, and I know we can access to Dashboard pages in local.

> **Authorization configuration required**
> By default Hangfire allows access to Dashboard pages only for local requests. In order to give appropriate rights for production use, please see the [Configuring Authorization](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization) section.

So you can refer the official article to implement it.